# Should there be a comma in the quote "At the end everything will be alright"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Needless to state, the comma wouldn't be necessary if you were to say

> Everything will be alright at the end

But what if you were to state

> At the end everything will be alright

Surely there is a pause between the word 'end' and 'everything', so would it be better to insert a comma between them?

Comment: "**In** the end" is probably more appropriate here, unless you say "**At** the end **of something**." Either way, it is an introductory clause, so a comma is to be expected.

Comment: @MorganFR: Intriguing. You are right about "In the end.." phrase being more common. This statement was intended to the stated in some place like a dark tunnel. I think your comment can be a suitable answer, could you expand it in the answer post?

Comment: A comma obsessive would put a comma there, but it's not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"At the end" is an [***introductory clause***](https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/comma/8/comma-after-introductory-clauses/) (although it can be placed at the end of the sentence). An introductory clause, as such, ***requires a comma*** before the main clause.

> The tunnel is dark. **At the end (of it),** you will find some light.

As for the preposition before "the end", if you are talking about the end **of something** previously mentioned or mentioned in the "**at** the end **of...**" itself, you can use "at". Otherwise, you might wanna use "**In** the end."

> **In** the end, it will be alright.

Comment: Upvote. I suggest you make that excellent attribution more prominent in your answer. Instead of "further reading", I think it qualifies as incontrovertible proof!